# How can I add line breaks in a wchar_t array?

Tags: c++, winapi, console, windows-console

I'm working on a console game. It uses a screen buffer to refresh the console window after updating the map.

Here's the main `while` loop.

```cpp
while (true) {
    //player.doStuff(_kbhit());
    //map.update();
    WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(
        console.getScreenBuffer(),
        (LPWSTR)map.getScreen(),
        map.getWidth() * map.getHeight(),
        { 0, 0 }, console.getBytesWritten()
    );
    Sleep(1000 / 30);
}
```

Before this loop, I'm getting the layout of the map from a `.txt` file:

```cpp
class Map {
    int width, height;
    wchar_t* screen;
public:
    wchar_t* getScreen() {
        return screen;
    }
    void setScreen(std::string layoutFile, std::string levelDataFile) {
        std::ifstream levelData(levelDataFile);
        levelData >> width >> height;
        screen = new wchar_t[(width + 1) * height];
        levelData.close();

        std::wifstream layout(layoutFile);
        std::wstring line;

        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            std::getline<wchar_t>(layout, line);
            for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
                screen[j * width + i] = line.at(i);
            }
            screen[width * (j + 1)] = L'\n';
        }
        layout.close();
    }
};


map.setScreen("demo.txt", "demo_data.txt");
```

The problem is that the printed map displays as one string without any line breaks, like this:

```
00000__00000
```

When I expected it to look like this instead:

```
0000
0__0 
0000
```

I tried adding `L'\n'`, `L'\r\n'` after every line written, but it doesn't work.

Comment: The length of a line is `width+1` including the line break. The formulae for the indices (`j * width + i` and `width * (j + 1)`) are wrong for this reason. Also be careful to end the string with a null char, not a line break.

Comment: @fabian but the problem is that getline returns only a string without the \n, and in that case the length of a line is `width` not `width+1`. Because of that i tried to make a map 1 symbol wider than a line, and adding a line break manually, which is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## In short

There are two independent problems here:

- The first one is that your newline characters get overwritten.
- The second, once you've corrected the first, is that the windows console API does not handle newlines

## More details

### The problem with the overwriting

I assume that the width does not include the trailing newline at the end of each line, since your allocation for the screen is:

```
new wchar_t[(width + 1) * height];   // real width is width + 1 for '\n'
```

Now looking at your logic,  the last `'\n'` that you add to the line,  is set at:

```
screen[ width * (j + 1) ]   // same as screen[ j * width + width ]
```

This seems fine according to your indexing scheme,  since you copy the layout characters to:

```
screen[ j * width + i ]`   // where `i` is between `0` and `width-1`
```

so the newline would be at `screen[ j * width + width ]`.

Unfortunately, with your indexing formula, the first character of the next line overwrites the same place: replacing `j` with `j+1` and `i` with `0` gives:

```
screen[ (j + 1) * width + 0 ]
```

which is

```
screen[ (j + 1) * width ]    // same location as screen [ width * (j+1)]
```

### The solution for having trailing newlines on very line

Correct your indexing scheme, taking into account that the real width of the line is `width+1`.

So the indexing formula becomes:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        screen[j * (width+1) + i] = line.at(i);
    }
```

and of course the trailing newline:

```
    screen[j * (width+1) + width] = L'\n';  // self-explaining
    screen[(j+1) * (width+1) -1] = L'\n';   // or alternative
```

### The problem with the console API

The [`WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutputcharacter) provides no real support for newlines and control characters. These are diplayed as a question mark.

The documentation refers to a possibility to get those control characters handled depending on the console mode,  but I've tried with Windows 10, and even with the variant `WriteConsoleOutputCharacterA()` (to be sure to exclude issues with wide characters), it simply does not work.

You have two solutions to make this work, but the two require some rework:

- display the output line by line and control the cursor position accordingly
- use the [`WriteConsoleOutput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsoleoutput) which allows you to specify the target rectangle (heigth and width) and write the characters in a rectangle without need for a newline.  Unfortunately,  the array shall then be of CHAR_INFO instead of simple characters.

Example for the second way:

```
std::string w = "SATORAREPOTENETOPERAROTAS";
SMALL_RECT sr{ 2, 2, 6, 6 };
CHAR_INFO t[25];
for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) { t[i].Char.AsciiChar = w[i]; t[i].Attributes = BACKGROUND_GREEN; }
WriteConsoleOutputA(
    hOut,
    t,
    { 5,5 },
    { 0,0 },
    &sr
);
```

Comment: that seems right but the output is still not correct: `0000?0  0?00`.

Comment: the program cant read \n for some reason, and it it writes `?` instead of making a linebreak

Comment: @kastrycznik it is not clear how you come to this '?'.  How do you read your output file and how do you display it?  Because in principle,  it should work even with a simple '\n' (see online demo: https://ideone.com/LcDpJI ).  Of course if you write to the windows console buffer, you should not add a new line, but write at the right place in the buffer.

Comment: im reading the output file line by line and then writing it to the wstring instead of wchar_t (like you said), then im displaying this string with this command: `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter( console.getScreenBuffer(), (LPWSTR)map.getScreen().c_str(), map.getWidth() * map.getHeight(), { 0, 0 }, console.getBytesWritten());` map.getScreen() returns std::wstring screen. I also had to use c_str() method on my wstring because `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter` takes only LPWSTR

Comment: i also tried to use `std::wcout << map.getScreen() << std::endl;`. In that case the output has line breaks, but when i use `WriteConsoleOutputCharacter()` question marks are displayed instead of line breaks

Comment: @kastrycznik Yes,  the low level console operations are not supposed to process non printable characters.  There are some options in the console mode, but I tried them and they seem not to work with windows 10 anymore.  I've edited my answer to address also this issue.